# How to get value from object angular using *ngFor?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript

[image: Image of JSON]

I have a json structure like the image above.

I just want to get the value from the key `name`.

I was do Like this :

```
<span *ngFor="let outlet of products.body | keyvalue">{{outlet.value}}</span>
```

but that way is to call all attributes, I only want to call attribute name. how do?

Sorry for bad grammar, any suggestion or answer will be appreciate. Thank you

Comment: i think that you don't need for ngFor on this JSON structure because it's not an array , so you can get the value directly using `{{body.name}}` , and if you have multi products so ngFor will be for the parent not for this section specially

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to get the value of `name` key, there is no need to use `*ngFor`.

It's enough to put it directly as follows.

```
<span>{{ products?.body?.name }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please bind

```
{{outlet.name}}
```

instead of {{outlet.value}}